# jquery datatable set width upon initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to set the width of a cell in a jQuery datatable upon initialization and it never seems to work. I've have tried what the [official site](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) recommends and other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990920/4896260). Below are some of the options I have tried. Please help on what I'm doing wrong?

Ex: 1

```
$('#dataTables-comments').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aoColumns": [{
            "sWidth": "50%"
        }, 
        {
            "sWidth": null
        },  
        {
            "sWidth": null
        },   
        {
            "sWidth": null
        },   
        {
            "sWidth": null
        }   
    ],
    "responsive": true
});
```

Ex: 2

```
$('#dataTables-tbl').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "50%",
        "targets": 0
    }],
    "responsive": true
});
```

Ex: 3

```
$('#dataTables-tbl').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "columns": [{
        "width": "50%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }],
    "responsive": true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any other usage of a CSS percentage value, the value *must* be a percentage of *something*. If the table itself not have a defined `width`, then `10%` is untranslatable. So give your table a `width` :

```css
#dataTables-comments {
  width: 800px;
}
```

and be sure to turn off [**`autoWidth`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) so dataTables not begin to overrule the predefined column widths :

```js
$('#dataTables-tbl').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false, //<---
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "columns": [{
        "width": "50%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }, {
        "width": "10%"
    }],
    "responsive": true
});
```

Comment: For reason it doesn't seem to recognize the width in the datatable, but adding the styling to the css file made it work. Thanks!